# On the derivation of the values of $E[X^s]$ with $s \in C$ from the moments.

Tags: probability, complex-analysis

Take $s \in C$ and an absolutely continuous random variable $X$ for which all moments exist and are given by $E[X^n] = f(n)$ for some continuous function $f$.

Then can we always say that $E[X^s] = f(s)$ where $f(s)$ is well defined?

To give an example say we have a random variable $B\sim Beta(a,b)$ we know that $E[B^n] = \frac{\beta(a+n,b)}{\beta(a,b)} \ \forall{n}\in N $ is it true that $E[B^s] = \frac{\beta(a+s,b)}{\beta(a,b)}$ where $s$ is a complex number with $Real(s) > -a$?

Comment: Given the integer moments exist and knowing their values, one can find the characteristic function, then find the density (or at least the CDF) uniquely, then calculate the more general moments in the usual way. Obviously your question needs some restrictions on what $s$ can be, as in your example. It is easy to check that in the example, the moment expressions do extend simply, by the Euler integral for the Beta-function.

Comment: @Chappers  Thank you very much, could you expand upon calculating these "more general moments in the usual way", I think this is what I am missing. Give me a reference if you wish. Thanks again.

Comment: @Chappers   Oh you mean just calculating the moments in the same way we did with an integer value? correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give the process in my comment in slightly more detail,

1. Given $E[X^n]$ for all $n \in \{0,1,2,\dotsc\}$, the characteristic function of the distribution is uniquely determined by its series expansion,
   $$ \varphi_X(t) = E[e^{itX}] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(it)^n}{n!} E[X^n]. $$
2. The characteristic function determines the distribution uniquely; since the random variable is absolutely continuous, the density can be recovered by [what is essentially Fourier inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formulae),
   $$ f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-itx} \varphi_X(t) \, dt. $$
3. The non-integral moments are then simply $E[X^s] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x^s f(x) \, dx$ by the usual formula. Note that this only really makes sense if $X$ is nonnegative, since $x^s$ can have different definitions for negative $x$ and it's not necessarily obvious which you want.

This is admittedly a rather crude approach, but it suffices for your example.

If the random variable is nonnegative and you don't have all the moments, $s \mapsto X^s$ is log-convex, which you can use to find a simple bound on moments smaller than the largest one you have:
$$ E[X^s] \leq (E[X^a])^{\alpha/a} (E[X^b])^{\beta/b}, $$
where $\alpha+\beta=s$ and $\alpha/a+\beta/b=1$.